# How does Google know about geo-location of a website for AdSense payments?

Tags: google, google-adsense, geolocation

According "AdSense" terms, Indian websites or blogs need to be 6 months old to participate in AdSense. Now I have two questions in my mind:

1. Firstly, how does Google know that a website is being run by an Indian?
2. Does six months old mean that the domain should be registered for 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [eligibility page for Google Adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724?hl=en) where it states:

> **Have you owned your site for 6 months?**
>
> In some locations, including China and India, we require publishers to have owned their sites for 6 months. We've taken this step to ensure the quality of our advertising network and protect the interests of our advertisers and existing publishers.

Then the [sign up page for adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense/signup) requires that you supply a postal address:

> **A postal address** -- The mailing address at which you receive your bank statements.
>
> Please be aware that you will not be able to sign up for AdSense without a valid postal address.

Google will apply this rule if the postal address that you supply where you can recieve your payments is located in India.  [Google validates this address](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/157667?hl=en) by sending you mail at this address with a PIN code on it that you have to enter into the Google website.

Google might also apply that rule if any of the following were true about the website/blog:

- Hosted on a `.in` top level domain
- Hosted on a server in India
- Content targeted to users in India

---

While the policy page doesn't make it clear if the age of the site is based on domain name age or content age, many people have asked about this in the Google forums.  There, several posts ([1](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/wUMSn_Zjmkc/ygq88HTTxwIJ), [2](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/yWcWBpcHIHI/aYJYiaIlHowJ)) make it clear that it is the age of the content that is important, not only the age of the domain name.

To get to the required level of content, spend those six months creating an article or blog post every day.  With 100 original articles over the course of six months, there will be plenty of content for an AdSense application.

---

[Google user i4c has the following sage advice](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/tfvMUnAnUJA/xj5penPe5jwJ) about the 6 month site ownership policy:

> The decision to ensure applications from India, China and 'certain other countries' was made simply because of the high number of poor quality applications from those countries, often thrown up overnight with cut and pasted content from other sites, which add nothing of value to the web and often wither and die due to a lack of development. Most of these sites are not of a quality that paying advertisers would wish their adverts to be associated with.
>
> Be assured that Google are now considering rolling out this requirement globally, so its nothing to do with racism, just an effective way of ensuring that only quality sites with realistic traffic get approved. Realistically, no site less than six months old would make anything from AdSense anyway as it takes at least that time to get established with a good flow of visitors. Without that flow, there would be no clicks and no money generated.

---

[Google user Cade warns that you shouldn't try to circumvent this policy](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/izFklzXz_YY/i7lBLHbJ99gJ):

> [You could] try to register your blog and be denied. If you somehow manage to slip though the Google scrutiny, your account will probably be disabled in the upcoming weeks. Once you get banned, it is for life. Do you really want to risk future Adsense earnings to make a few pennies per month?
>
> Take six months, work on creating 100 pages of original and relevant content, then apply for Adsense.